# post data to url of soap server using wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, soap, post

I am new to wordpress.

I want to post data to some url which of soap server.

for this can i use wp_remote_post method?

If no then tell me what is the way to do this?

please help me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use wp_remote_post to communicate with a soap server. This just makes a post request to a url. If you want to communicate with SOAP you have to create a SOAP object, make sure it conforms to the WSDL service and make calls through it. This sounds like it is far over your head. You should read some tutorials on SOAP and PHP.

http://devzone.zend.com/article/689

Comment: thanks! Yeah you are right. I am a student. I have no knowledge about this things. thanks again.